# Why my nginx(engine-x) is not listening my request.?

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

I have have created a small app and run as per the instructions given by the below url

http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/08/minimal-nginx-and-gunicorn-configuration-for-djang/

I have created a `example` file in the `/iec/nginx/sites-enabled` directory.And my example file contains the below code

```
server {
listen localhost:8000;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}

location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/mulagala/nginx_example/mysite/static/;
}
}
```

But when i tried to connect `localhost:8000` i am getting error unable to connect.Why my `nginx` server is not listening my request. What mistake i am doing.Any help would be appriciated

Comment: check that nginx is actually running (ps -e | grep nginx) and listening on the 8000 port (netstat -antp | grep 8000)

Comment: @Pixou, Yes i checked with `service nginx status` its is running